# RESTful WebService consumes XML,how to call it?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, call

**UPDATE**

I have almost been able to complete my RESTful communication, though I have to questions remaining:

1 - How do I assign my XML to the connection (the code below will give an example of my situation)?

*Calling the Web Service*

```
public Person getByAccount(Account account) {   
    URL url = new URL(uri);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    String xmlIn = xstream.toXML(account);

    // Put the xmlIn into the connection

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (connection.getInputStream())));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(line);
    String xmlOut = sb.toString();

    connection.disconnect();
    return (Person) xstream.fromXML(xmlOut);
}
```

2 - Will the class below result in a valid XML-output, considering the last code example (the Web Service)?

*Class to send using RESTful*

```
@XmlRootElement(name="people")
public class People {
    @XmlElement(name="person")
    public List<Person> people;

    public People() {
        people.add(new Person(1, "Jan"));
        people.add(new Person(2, "Hans"));
        people.add(new Person(3, "Sjaak"));
    }

    public List<Person> all() {
        return people;
    }

    public Person byName(String name) {
        for(Person person : people)
            if(person.name.equals(name))
                return person;

        return null;
    }

    public void add(Person person) {
        people.add(person);
    }

    public Person update(Person person) {
        for(int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)
            if(person.id == people.get(i).id) {
                people.set(i, person);
                return person;
            }

        return null;
    }

    public void remove(Person person) {
        people.remove(person);
    }
}
```

*Web Service*

```
@GET
@Path("/byAccount")
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Person getByAccount(Account account) {
    // business logic
    return person;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream output = conn.getOutputStream();
// And write your xml to output stream.
```

Check this link for using REST with standard `URL`: http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-java.html

EDIT

First of all, you need to change your `getByAccount` request to `POST` request, because `GET` request doesn't allow to pass any information in body, it uses only request parameters in url. But you send XML, so use `POST`.

Try following version of your send method:

```
public Person getByAccount(Account account) {   
    URL url = new URL(uri);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
    connection.setOutput(true);

    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.toXML(account, connection.getOutputStream());

    Person person = (Person) xstream.fromXML(connection.getInputStream());   
    connection.disconnect();
    return person;
}
```

Comment: I have indeed seen a lot of example using InputStream and OutputStream. Though, in the case above (updated my question) I do not know how to make it work. How can I resolve this situation? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Thanks Nikita!
This solution simplifies my code and does a great job.

Comment: if his request is idempotent, shouldn't he be using PUT instead of POST ?

Comment: @MohamedSaligh link fixed https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/java-ee/producing-and-consuming-json-or-xml-in-java-rest-services-with-jersey-and-jackson

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Jersey Client API](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with), ([one more link](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html)) for most sufficient calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Spring 3 `RestTemplate`. Very easy to get started and quite powerful.

More here:
http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

http://www.baeldung.com/2012/04/16/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring-3-1/